# Pytest Assertions are catching the error but the test is not being marked as failed

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, assert

I'm using PyCharm as IDE, I'm testing some API results using 'assert', the console shows that the assertion is failing, however the test is still displayed as "Passed" with a green checkmark

```
try:
    api_request = APIRequest()
    # Make a GET request to the API with the API key in the headers
    response = api_request.get_response(f"{self.api_url}{id}", self.api_key)
    # assert the response was successful
    assert response.status_code == 200, f"Expected status code 200, but received {response.status_code}"
    # Parse the JSON response
    response_data = json.loads(response.text)
    # Assert that the response contains specific entries
    assert response_data["key"] == id, f'Key \'{id}\' not found in the response.'
    assert response_data[
               "filename"] == file.filename, f"Filename \'{file.filename}\' not found in the response."

    json_data = response_data.get("jsondata")
    if json_data:
        assert json_data[
                   "fiscal_year"] == file.fiscal_year, f"Expected \'{file.fiscal_year}\' not found \'{json_data["fiscal_year"]}\' in 'jsondata'."
        assert json_data[
                   "tax_amount_due"] == file.tax_amount_due, f"Expected \'{file.tax_amount_due}\' not found \'{json_data["tax_amount_due"]}\' in 'jsondata'."
        

    # Extract and print the response body
    response_data = response.json()
    print('Response body:')
    print(response_data)

except Exception as e:
    print('Error:', e)
```

I get the following error from the console:

```
Error: Expected '2023' not found '2022' in 'jsondata'.
```

but the test is marked as passed

[image]

In project settings I have already defined pytest as the default test runner.

Why I'm getting the green checkmark if the test is failing.

Comment: The test DIDN'T fail.  *You* caught the exception generated by `assert`, and chose not to pass it on by reraising it.

Comment: You were right, I removed the try/catch and now the test is being displayed as failing